# Xamarin Forms using FirebasePushNotificationPlugin plugin with Autofac and Shell unable to display UI elements nor redirects

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm experiencing an issue that I've tried different ways to resolve and have been unsuccessful with. Whenever receiving a message via CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived I get the payload and can read it, but I can't do anything "visual" in my app. In other words, I get the notification but when I want to either redirect to another page or even display a DisplayAlert message, nothing happens. MessagingCenter can be received, but any instructions within the procedure that have to do with redirecting or DisplayAlert (anything changing the UI it appears) will not be executed.
Looking for help in how to visually show in the app the user has received a message.

This is in MainShell.xaml.cs (I've also placed it in App.xaml.cs too):

```
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
```

{

```
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");  // this works
        foreach (var data in p.Data)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{data.Key} : {data.Value}"); // this works
        }

        //TODO:  Code to determine if user is signed in
        if (true)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug:  Goto Registration page from MainShell"); // this works
            //Task.Run(async () => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("registration"));  // this does not work (just ignores it and doesn't fire constructor)                    
            //Task.Run(async () => await Current.DisplayAlert("Request Received", "A message is waiting...", "Ok"));  // this does not work
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "RequestReceived"); // this works, the receiver will display debug info, but will not redirect nor display any UI messages or interact with the UI.

        }

    };
```

Thank you for any help or guidance,

Robert

Comment: you need to use MainThread to ensure UI operations are happening on the UI thread. See the Xamarin Essentials docs

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I had just discovered that solution not long afterward.  Good to know I was headed in the right direction.  Added it to App.xaml.cs and everything is working as expected.